# White space created when Navbar div has Position:fixed;

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I would like to get rid of the white space in the middle of the page under the Navigation Bar. But after trying lots of things and the white bar still existing, I'm confused.

Here is my code:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css"/>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="header">

        <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a>About</a></li>
            <li><a>Projects I've worked on</a></li>
            <li><a>Impossible List</a></li>
            <li><a>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- end navbar div-->

    <div class="content">
    <p id = "title">Srikant Devarajan</p>

    </div>
    <!--end content div-->
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum quidem quae magnam, facilis laborum minus provident. Earum ipsum quo voluptate cumque assumenda quia officiis, eaque suscipit error quae, maxime modi.</p>
<br>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum quidem quae magnam, facilis laborum minus provident. Earum ipsum quo voluptate cumque assumenda quia officiis, eaque suscipit error quae, maxime modi.</p>
<br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum quidem quae magnam, facilis laborum minus provident. Earum ipsum quo voluptate cumque assumenda quia officiis, eaque suscipit error quae, maxime modi.</p>
<br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum quidem quae magnam, facilis laborum minus provident. Earum ipsum quo voluptate cumque assumenda quia officiis, eaque suscipit error quae, maxime modi.</p>
<br>


</body>
<!--end body-->
</html>
<!--end html-->
```

Here is my CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300);

html,body{
    height:100%;
}
.header{ 
  background: url(images/background5.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   background-size: cover;
   height:100%;
}
.navbar{
    color:white;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    widows: 100%;
}

.navbar ul{
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar li{
    display: inline;
    padding:70px;
    color:#CCCCCC;
}

.navbar a:hover{
    color:#fff;
}

.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    opacity:2.0;
}
#title{
    margin-top:110px;
    font-size:70px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-family:'Lato';
}

.content p{
    margin-top:70px;
    font-size:35px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-family:'Lato';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you position something as fixed, imagine the browser no longer sees it as taking up space. Your whitespace is created by your margin-top in your title ID. Try tinkering with that value and see if the white space changes.

Edit: Indeed. It's the margin-top in your title ID.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I got it to finally work. I added some Line breaks before the title ID and it moved the title down and got rid of the white space